# MySQL - Use GROUP_CONCAT values in a calculation?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am trying to create a query which will give me a product's value after a number of discounts have been taken off its initial value.

This is a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
SELECT
p.price
GROUP_CONCAT(d.amount) AS discounts
FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN discounts d
ON d.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Where discounts.amount is a decimal value.

Edit: For example, if there were two corresponding discounts with values 10 and 15 respectively and the initial product price was 50, the calculation would return 25

Is there anyway within the query that I can perform the calculation that I want?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post example data and desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a SUM() method:

```
SELECT p.price,
       p.price - COALESCE(SUM(d.amount), 0) as discounted_price,
       GROUP_CONCAT(d.amount) AS discounts
FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN discounts d
ON d.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: I think I might be able to get this to do what I need, thanks!

Comment: Works without the COALESCE in.

Comment: I added coalesce because I'm unsure how MySQL reacts when it finds no matching joins on discounts. If this results in null (as is done in Postgres), you need coalesce to avoid getting a null value as the discounted_price.